# How can I run swift code in Struct ContentView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm very new to SwiftUI and Xcode and very less knowledge in Class, Stuct and function() in Swift. I'm trying to put my code inside to ContentView View{}. Because I couldn't see the result of this code on the (UI)user interface. Also, I couldn't find a good article on how this code runs in Sturct ContnetView.Here is the code I want to run.

```
import Cocoa

let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .excludeDesktopElements, .optionOnScreenOnly)
let windowsListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
let infoList = windowsListInfo as! [[String:Any]]
let visibleWindows = infoList.filter{ $0["kCGWindowLayer"] as! Int == 0 }

print(visibleWindows)
```

ContentView looks like,

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When I put code inside to View{}. It gives errors.

Comment: You can use the .onAppear()  view modifier and read up on the SwiftUI basics.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your SwiftUI code like "View Builder Code". The first snippet  you provided is "Logical Code".

Your SwiftUI View Builder code is intended to *describe* your view. When you add logical code in there, SwiftUI wouldn't know *when* to run it.

For instance, you can tell SwiftUI to run the code when the view appears using the `.onAppear` modifier.

```swift
Text("Hello, world!")
    .padding()
    .onAppear {
        // Your Logical Code
        let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .excludeDesktopElements, .optionOnScreenOnly)
        let windowsListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
        let infoList = windowsListInfo as! [[String:Any]]
        let visibleWindows = infoList.filter{ $0["kCGWindowLayer"] as! Int == 0 }

        print(visibleWindows)
    }
```

For your use case, you might want to consider creating a [@State variable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) with an array of `visibleWindows` or even a [computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It works. But still, I have a problem. Because the result is only shown in the terminal. How does it appear in the hello world window(User Interface)?

Comment: Have you done any **basic** tutorial on SwiftUI? Have a look at this link: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/ 
 it will give you the answer.